# Struts2 with SpringSecurity and Tiles

Tags: spring, spring-security, struts2

I need to integrate Struts2 with Spring Security. For now i successfully added spring and spring security to my project but i can't log in to my application. I don't have any idea what can be wrong.

Using dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <struts.version>2.3.24.1</struts.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysqlconnector.version>5.1.34</mysqlconnector.version>

    <javaee-web-api.version>7.0</javaee-web-api.version>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
    <jsp-api-version>2.1</jsp-api-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts 2 annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts 2 AJAX support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- Spring -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- struts 2 & spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate 4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql java connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysqlconnector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp-api-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<display-name>Struts 2 - NSAI</display-name>
<!-- load spring configuration: -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--Struts Filter-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <!-- load tiles configuration: -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- tiles listener: -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nsai" />
    <property name="username" value="nsaiuser" />
    <property name="password" value="nsaipassword" />
</bean>

<!--Hibernate session factory configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.politechnika.models" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.politechnika" /> 
<import resource="classpath*:spring-security.xml"/>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/showUsersList.action" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/executeLogin.action" access="permitAll"/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/views/accessDenied.jsp" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/inputLogin.action"
        default-target-url="/"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider> 

    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<div id="login">
<s:form name="loginFrom" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <s:textfield key="user.login" name="username"/>
    <s:password key="user.password" name="password"/>
    <s:submit key="submit"/>
</s:form>
<p>
    <a href="<s:url action='showUsersList'/>">List of users</a>
</p>
```

When im trying to login application redirect me to AccesDenied page and when i'am trying go to another page it autommatically redirect me to login page.

What is wrong there?

UPDATE:
I added log4j for spring security and when i'am trying log in i'm getting this:

```
    2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:171 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:171 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:101 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@45e88786. A new one will be created.
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:101 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@45e88786. A new one will be created.
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@508596c1
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@508596c1
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG CsrfFilter:106 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/nsai-struts2/j_spring_security_check
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG CsrfFilter:106 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/nsai-struts2/j_spring_security_check
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2017-11-05 18:49:28 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**UPDATE2:**
I added csrf to the jsp file and still won't work.
Log (cannot paste here becouse limit is 30000 characters):

https://pastebin.com/SWT3ZCgp

Comment: If you think this is the issue with the csrf you can disable to confirm it. Your conf looks *old* for spring-security 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_csrf` as below:

```
<s:form name="loginFrom" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <s:textfield key="user.login" name="username"/>
    <s:password key="user.password" name="password"/>
<input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <s:submit key="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: I added this and still won't wok. Added log to my post under "update2".